# Are these x-rays consistent with a broken arm on a 6-year-old girl?

Tags: orthopedics, x-rays

I found these x-rays ([one](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KppMJotJki5sQ9OgyVGYKkNR0bjF_QJo) and [two](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DN8n4bfcfszX3m5SVIh-llx_ms4fE3iv)) in a box of stuff from my mother, and I know she had broken her arm in 1939 when she was 6:

[image]

Are these x-rays consistent with a girl of her age?  Does the number on the image contain any information that would narrow down when the x-rays were taken?  (yes she was living in Denver)

Comment: Unusual question for this site, and it's pretty clearly off topic, but I'll allow it at least for a while in case someone has insight, but it would probably get better answers on History.SE.

Comment: For what it's worth, by combining the legible letters across the two images, you can make out the doctor's name as G.F.Wollgast, MD, which, with an Internet search, matches a doctor of that name in Denver around that time.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X-rays normally contain identification [markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_marker) to indicate the side, the date, possibly name and other information.  It looks like you've cut part of the x-rays off but it looks like there's a treating MD's name at the top.

The date could be 9th August 1939, and the 1636 a clinic ID or something else.  It's not a timestamp as it's the same in both x-rays.  The L means left arm.

It clearly is an x-ray of a [greenstick fracture](https://bmcmusculoskeletdisord.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2474-13-6) of the distal radius in a child, because the epiphyses have not yet fused.